# Convert internal UserControl into third-party control without violating MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ChildUserControl` with view-model like this:

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel(HugeSettings settings)
    {
        // process settings
    }

    public int SelectedItemsCount { get; internal set; }

    // ... and many other properties which should be read-only from outside.
}
```

When all controls are in single project, `ParentUserControl` will use `ChildUserControl` like this:

```
<ParentUserControl ... >
    <ChildUserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />
</ParentUserControl>
```

And view-model:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        this.ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel(new HugeSettings());
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation omitted
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

In this scenario, I can initialize `ChildViewModel` simply with constructor, and I can get any `ChildViewModel` property directly inside `ParentViewModel` without worrying whether any views or user controls exists.

**The problem is** that `ChildUserControl` needed to be placed into *separate library* for sharing with other applications (they will use `ChildUserControl` as third-party control). In that case foreign program shouldn't directly manipulate `ChildViewModel`, because third-party user control normally should be used like this:

```
<ForeignUserControl ... >
    <ChildUserControl HugeSettings="{Binding Setting}" SelectedItemsCount="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
</ForeignUserControl>
```

As soon as I have **many** read-only properties besides `SelectedItemsCount`, it seems that I have only one choice: create  dependency properties in `UserControlChild`'s code-behind and connect them with corresponding view-model's properties.

Is this approach correct? Does better approach exists?

### Update

Googling "mvvm third party user controls" gives me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809901/expose-the-properties-of-a-usercontrol-which-is-built-in-mvvm) with **very** similar issue. There asker decided to use dependencies properties in code-behind.
So I have a choice:
1. Create DP in code-behind for every needed property in view-model and link each pair. (violates MVVM?)
2. Just move all view-model logic to code-behind and convert properties to DP. Definitely violated MVVM, but there is [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637830/5177728) that "MVVM is **not** a good choice if you are developing a UserControl that will be consumed by others".

What should I prefer? Is there another choice?

Comment: When I have "custom controls" I make them completely outside of MVVM. A TextBox isn't MVVM. A control might *support* MVVM, but that only really applies with very complex controls like docking managers or something. Normal controls exist outside of that pattern. How many properties do you have?

Comment: @Joe I have about 10 properties, but it definitely will be more in future. And according to my resent research I agree with you that custom control _is not_ and _should not_ be MVVM. But I'm going to use this fact as my advantage: custom control will just create `ChildViewModel` and assign it to `DataContext` of `ChildUserControl` defined in `Generic.xaml`. In that case not only `ChildViewModel` remains untouchable, but it even remains in MVVM scope. As for read-only properties - I will just expose all of them through single complex dependency property of custom control.

Comment: @Joe But I can't definitely say whether this plan is technically good or awful, so any remarks are welcome. I can only say that this plan is convenient in my case because `ChildUserControl` is complex enough and rewriting it will take a time.